# Graphing an arcsin function using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to graph this function using pgfplots:

```
D(x)=180+2x-4(arcsin(sin(x)/1.33))
```

What is the how to I represent this in the the addplot function in pgfplots? I am also confused as to what to add in my preamble.

Thanks for the help,
A new member of the community

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    samples=300,
    %axis equal image,
    %xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    axis lines=middle, enlargelimits=true
]
\addplot [
    no markers,
    blue,
    thick,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi
] {pi+2*x-4*(asin(sin(x)/1.33))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `x` in degrees,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %trig format plots=rad,
    samples=300,
    %axis equal image,
    %xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    axis lines=middle, enlargelimits=true
]
\addplot [
    no markers,
    blue,
    thick,
    domain=-10:10
] {180+2*deg(x)-4*(asin(sin(deg(x))/1.33))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I got the function up and running. Is there any way to restrict the range of the function? Say from 130 degrees to 180 degrees?

Comment: @SidharthaJha: Change the domain.